# Div hidden in white background in mobile device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am creating a web page layout using bootstrap and the backend is Laravel, the web page is partitioned into various divs which work fine on various screen devices but when I upload the project on a live server and view the page on mobile part of the service and contact section is hidden behind a white background, I find it hard to figure out the problem in CSS code,,,please assist?

**Code**

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Pacifico Regular'), local('Pacifico-Regular'), url("../fonts/pacifico.woff") format('woff');
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img,
object,
embed,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/*Service section*/

.service-heading {
  font-size: 22px;
}

#service {
  background: url(../img/bg/number1.gif) repeat center center fixed;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
}

#service h3,
p {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#service .block-heading h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Milonga', cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 55px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
}


/*Contact section*/

#contact {
  background: url(../img/bg/contact-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
}

#contact .block-heading h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Milonga', cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 55px;
}

.overlay-3 {
  padding: 60px 0;
  /* background-color: rgba(9, 20, 39, 0.83); */
  /* background-color: rgba(24, 77, 77, 0.93); */
  background-color: rgba(33, 103, 88, 0.9);
}

.contact-info {
  padding: 16px 62px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

. .contact-info i {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 7px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.contact-info p {
  padding: 27px 10px;
}

.contact-info span {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
textarea {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s background linear;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s background linear;
  color: #333;
}

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}

 ::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #fff;
}

 :-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  #service {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background: blue;
  }
  .overlay-3 {
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #contact {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
  <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=3.0">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico"> >

  <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- google font -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400' rel='stylesheet'>

</head>

<body>



  <!--  Service Section -->
  <div class="content-block" id="service">
    <br><br>
    <header class="block-heading cleafix text-center">
      <h1> Services</h1>
      <!-- <p>Lorem Ipsum Text</p> -->
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted"> Welcome </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
          <h4 class="service-heading"> School Of Arts</h4>
          <p>...............</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
          <h4 class="service-heading">School of Business </h4>
          <p> ........... </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-code fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
          <h4 class="service-heading"> School of Engineering </h4>
          <p> ........ </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-wordpress fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
          <h4 class="service-heading"> School of Human Resource</h4>
          <p> ........ </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
          <h4 class="service-heading"> School of Medicine </h4>
          <p> ........ .......</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
          <h4 class="service-heading"> School of Biological Sciences </h4>
          <p> .......... </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END SERVICE SECTION-->



  <!-- Contact Form Section-->
  <div class="content-block" id="contact">
    <div class="overlay-3">
      <header class="block-heading cleafix text-center">
        <h1>Contact</h1>
        <!-- <p>Feel Free to Contact</p> -->
      </header>
      <div class="block-content text-center">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">

            <!-- Form Section -->
            <div class="col-sm-4 wow animated fadeInLeft">


              {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'index.post', 'method' => 'POST','class' => 'contact-form')) !!} {{ Form::text('name', null, array( 'placeholder' => 'Name...', 'class' => 'input', 'required' => ''))}} {{ Form::email('email', null, array('placeholder'
              => 'Email Address...','class' => 'input', 'required' => ''))}} {{ Form::textarea('message', null, array('placeholder' => 'Message...', 'class' => '', 'required' => 'input')) }} {{ Form::submit('Submit') }} {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>

            <!-- Adress -->
            <div class="col-sm-4 wow animated fadeInRight">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="contact-info">
                    <div class="clearfix">
                      <div class="rotated-icon">
                        <div class="sqaure-nebir"></div>
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                      </div>
                      <p><strong> 3069 Nkr</strong> </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="tel clearfix">
                      <div class="rotated-icon">
                        <div class="sqaure-nebir"></div>
                        <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>
                      </div>
                      <p>
                        <strong> <a class="tell" href="tel:+256123456" rel="nofollow"> +256 123456 </a> </strong>
                        <br>
                        <strong> <a class="tell" href="tel:+256547890" rel="nofollow"> +254 756789098</a> </strong>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                      <div class="rotated-icon">
                        <div class="sqaure-nebir"></div>
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                      </div>
                      <p>
                        <strong> info@tcol.com </strong>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">

                <ul class="social-box">
                  <li>
                    <a class="facebook-icon" href="https://www.facebook.com/pwebkenya" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <a class="twitter-icon" href="https://twitter.com/pwebkenya" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                  </li>

                  <li><a class="g-plus-icon" href="https://github.com/patwan"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>

                  <li> <a class="linkedin-icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </div>

            <!-- photo -->
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <br> <br>
              <div class="team-member">
                <img src="img/7.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="">
                <h4> Steve Johns</h4>
                <p class="text-muted"> Web Developer/Graphics Designer</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END PHOTO-->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- block-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- overlay-3 -->
  </div>
  <!-- content-block -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello Patwan, can you provide a JSfiddle working with your issue ?

Comment: @RémyTesta Do you mean JavaScript code used with the page?

Comment: The id used with contact has not been  used in Js instead I have used it in CSS,, No Js has been used to hide or show divs

Comment: Yes maybe try to isolate the issue on a minimalist Jsfiddle or provide your production link if you have one ?

Comment: It's just hard to debug only reading code

Comment: Hmmmhh, Dont have a production links,,, perhaps I thought maybe my CSS code had some errors,cause all other divs are displkaying well except these 2 divs

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your HTML in the 'contact' section:

```
<header class="block-heading cleafix text-center">``
```

Therefore, the floats are not cleared on this element. Don't know if it fixes the entire problem though.